# How to fix my "non-static variable q1 cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: compiler-errors

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Circle3
{
public static class Windows extends Frame
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            int x1 = 1;
            int x = 1;
            int y = 1;
            int y1 = 1;
            for(x = 100;x<=177;x++)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                CC one = new CC(x);
                g.fillPolygon(CC.q,CC.q1,3);
                for(int z = 0;z<50000;z++)
                {
                    for(int u = 0;u<1000;u++)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Windows w = new Windows();
    w.setSize(800,800);
    w.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){System.exit(0);}});
    w.show();
}
}
```

This is my main portion of my code of which the error occurs on line 20: g.fillPolygon(CC.q,CC.q1,3). I'm not sure why I am getting this error but I am a sort of novice at coding right now. This next code is my class CC.

```
 public class CC
{
public CC(int a)
{
    x = a;
    x1 = x+1;
    y = (int)(100-Math.sqrt(22500-Math.pow(x-100,2)));
    y1 = (int)(100-Math.sqrt(22500-Math.pow(x1-100,2)));
    q = new int[]{x+300,x1+300,400};
    q1 = new int[]{y+300,y1+300,400};
}
public int x;
public int x1;
public int y;
public int y1;
public int[] q;
public int[] q1;
 }
```

This is code to draw and fill a circle if you were wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason you are getting the error is because in the call to fillPolygon you are referencing q and q1 through the class and not an instance of the class.  You should be passing one.q and one.q1 rather than CC.q and CC.q1.

Comment: Yeah I realized that about 20 seconds ago... I feel stupid now.

Comment: It happens.  Were you also getting the same error for q?  It seems weird that it would only give the error on q1.